# How to figure out N threads I need in a parallel execution context?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I'm working in a redelivery system. This system attempt to execute an action, if the action fails, it try to execute again two times with an interval of five minutes, so I use the `ExecutorService` implementation to perform the first execution and `ScheduledExecutorService` to schedule the other ones, depending of its results (fail).

What should I consider to figure out the number of threads I need? In this moment I use only a single thread model (created by `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor` method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing details about the load your system has, environment it is using and how long does it take to process one message it is hard to say which number of threads you need. However, you can think of the following base principles:

1. Having many threads is bad, because you'll spend significant amount of time on a context switch, the chance of starvation and wasting system resources is higher .
2. Each thread consumes some space in memory for its stack. On `x64` it is typically `1MB` per thread.

I would probably create 2 thread pools (one scheduled, one non-scheduled)  for both sending and redelivery and test them under high load varying number of threads from 2 to 10 to see which number suits best.

Answer (score 0):

You should only need the one thread as only one action is running at a time. You could use a CachedThreadPool and not worry about it.